# Set personalized body for sending mail in django

Tags: python, django, smtp

I want to send a message with personalized SMTP mail-in Django. Where I want to send the Name, email, and contact information with the dynamic text input value.

Here is my code

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
      name = request.POST.get('name')
      email = request.POST.get('email')
      contact = request.POST.get('contactnum')
      textmess = request.POST.get('textarea')
      allinfo = "Name : " + name, "E-Mail" + email, "Contact:" + contact, textmess
      print (allinfo)
      subject = 'From MBS Project(Contact Us)'
      email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
      mailto:recipents_list=['abc@gmail.com']
      if allinfo:
        sendMail = send_mail(subject, allinfo, email_from, recipents_list)
        messages.success(request, 'Message Send Successfully...')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('contactus', {'sendMail': sendMail})
      else:
        messages.error(request, 'error during send!!, Please Try Again..')
        return render(request, 'contactus.html', {})
   else:
      return render(request, 'contactus.html', {})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The commas in this line don't look right:

```
allinfo = "Name : " + name, "E-Mail" + email, "Contact:" + contact, textmess
```

You might want:

```
allinfo = "Name: " + name + " E-Mail: " + email + "Contact: " + contact + textmess
```

Or better, use f-strings: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings

```
allinfo = f"Name: {name} E-Mail: {email} Contact: {contact} {textmess}"
```

Comment: Thanks, with this `allinfo = "Name: " + name + " E-Mail: " + email + "Contact: " + contact + textmess` I got my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use templates to configure mail information.

For example, here is my contact form mail template:

```
{% autoescape off %}
Message from <my project> contact form:

From: {{ name }} ({{ email }})
{% if user.email %}
User: {{ user.display_name }} ({{ user.email }})
{% endif %}

{{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

I then use this when sending a mail as follows:

```
    send_mail(
        subject=f"CONTACT FORM: {subject}",
        message=render_to_string(
            template_name="project/email/contact_us_body.html",
            context={
                "name": from_name,
                "email": from_email,
                "user": user,
                "body": body,
            },
        ),
        from_email=settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL,
        recipient_list=[
            contact_tuple[1] for contact_tuple in settings.ADMINS if contact_tuple[1] is not None
        ],
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

You can use this templating for mail bodies, subjects, or basically any text at all, just by calling `render_to_string`.